# Некорректный старт сервера

Tags: mysql, linux, tomcat

При старте ubuntu 14 tomcat стартует автоматом но не видит бд и выводит 500 статус на реквесты, как можно это исправить? 
При рестарте из IDE все работает корректно.

Comment: А бд тоже стартует автоматом или она на другом сервере?

Comment: все на localhost, тоже подозрения что mysql не стартует при запуске системмы. Как можно проверить?

Comment: сразу после запуска системы попробуйте проверить `sudo service mysql status` или `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status`.

Comment: mysql start/running, process 1054

Comment: 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart' выдает:  * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                   [ OK ] 
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                   [ OK ] 
 * Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly.
ниче не пойму

Comment: после рестарта mysql база для томката доступна?

Comment: видимо нет, в папке var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT лежит весь проект а к базе не конектится собака

Comment: проверьте конфигурацию подключения приложения к бд, если нужно - прикрепите к вопросу.

Comment: Надо дебажить БД. Для начала попытаться самостоятельно приконнектиться к БД с теми реквизитами, что использует tomcat.

Comment: бд работает отлично, по крайней мере из Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в JDK tomcat7. Peшение нашлось тут : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052127/how-to-setup-tomcat7-in-ubuntu-14-04-so-that-it-uses-latest-jre-of-java-8-oracle.
Cпасибо nobody и Alex Chermenin за помошь.